# LASSO method. Intuitively how does it select variables?

Tags: machine-learning, lasso

Intuitively how does the LASSO method select its variables?

Is it based on standard econometrics?

Comment: @Tim: In the link you give the question is "I would like to know why the Lasso provides variable selection and ridge regression doesn't.". That seems to be a different question to me. If this question wouldn't be marked as a dup0licate I would like to post an answer.

Comment: @boulder this question was already answered in several places, I added few more links as duplicaes.

Comment: @Tim: Okay, I did not know that. Thank you.